# Flutter Icon Button Speed Dial

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

Is there an existing speed dial widget that would work with regular buttons or any onclick event? I have found [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_speed_dial) widget which works great with the FloatingActionButton, but I need something that would work with an IconButton or RaisedButton. I tried using the SpeedDial Widget inside of a container, like so:

```
Container(
                  child: SpeedDial(
                    overlayOpacity: 0.2,
                    animatedIcon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
                    children: [
                      SpeedDialChild(
                        child: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                        label: 'Second',
                        onTap: () => print('SECOND'),
                      ),
                      SpeedDialChild(
                        child: Icon(Icons.accessibility),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        label: 'First',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                        onTap: () => print('FIRST'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

But no luck, unfortunately. I get an infinity pixels on the right.

Answer (score 2):

Please use padding in right and bottom side. Check the below code. You need to set a TextStyle for Text, you also need to use manual height and width for your child.

```
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 20, 20),
      child: Container(
        child: SpeedDial(
          overlayOpacity: 0.2,
          animatedIcon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
          children: [
            SpeedDialChild(
              child: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
              label: 'Second',
              onTap: () => print('SECOND'),
            ),
            SpeedDialChild(
              child: Icon(Icons.accessibility),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              label: 'First',
              labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
              onTap: () => print('FIRST'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Question about the height and width of the child. Are you talking about the SpeedDialChild?

Comment: No, use in the parent